# NameError: name 'helloworld' is not defined

Tags: python, apache, flask

**My files are as follows:**

helloworld.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def __init__(self):
    print 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

application.wsgi

```
import os
import sys


sys.path.append('/srv/www/mysite.com/application')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/srv/www/mysite.com/.python-egg'

import flaskr.helloworld
application = helloworld
```

When attempting to run this through my web browser, the module is loaded fine. I end up receiving a 500 error, with this in my error.log "NameError: name 'helloworld' is not defined"

Any ideas why?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import flaskr.helloworld as helloworld
application = helloworld.app
```

Or alternatively:

```
import flaskr.helloworld
application = flaskr.helloworld.app
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I think Joachim beat you by a few seconds though :).

Comment: @DeliciousMangos: Indeed he did. I edited my answer to (hopefully) solve your other problem.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the code and for whatever reason it is still giving me an error, but with nothing in my error.log.

Comment: I've moved this new problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713794/internal-server-error-with-hello-world-python-app

Answer (score 1):

In application.wsgi, how about replacing the last line with

```
application = flaskr.helloworld
```

Or replace the import with

```
import flaskr.helloworld as helloworld
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, however I now have a new error, "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"