# "Internal Server Error" with Hello World Python App

Tags: python, flask, internal-server-error

**My files are as follows:**

application.wsgi (**NOTE:** updated as recommended from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713378/nameerror-name-helloworld-is-not-defined))

```
import os
import sys


sys.path.append('/srv/www/mysite.com/application')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/srv/www/mysite.com/.python-egg'

import flaskr.helloworld
application = flaskr.helloworld.app
```

helloworld.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def __init__(self):
    print 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

For what ever reason I get the following error when attempting to load. Nothing is added to my error.log, it just displays this in the browser: "Internal Server Error"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `print 'Hello World!'` to `return 'Hello World!'`

Comment: Ohhhh... how embarrassing! Thank you!

Comment: @keni It told me I had to wait 10 minutes and I had to go out.

Comment: What is the general approach to debugging a flask application though?